# How to speed up the deletion of entries from a table with a large number of entries

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization

I have a table that currently has over 150 million records. The table has no foreign keys.

[image: [TABLE]]

The database was previously based on MySQL and was migrated to SQL Server.
Since then, one specific query on that table has taken much, much longer.
On MySQL, the query counterpart took less than 3 seconds to execute. On SQL Server, the query can be executed even for more than 1 minute.

There is no problem with any other table or query at the moment - just this one on this one table.

[EXAMPLE] : I CAN'T CHANGE A QUERY.

```
delete from Features WITH(ROWLOCK)
where ParentType=N'DokHandlowe' and Parent=3023658
   or ParentType=N'PozycjeDokHan' and Parent in (25302311, 25302312, 
25302313, 25302314, 25302315, 25302316, 25302317, 25302318, 25302319, 
25302320, 25302321, 25302322, 25302323, 25302324, 25302325, 25302326, 
25302327, 25302328, 25302329, 25302330, 25302331, 25302332, 25302333, 
25302334, 25302335, 25302336, 25302337, 25302338, 25302339, 25302340, 
25302341, 25302342, 25302343, 25302344, 25302345, 25302346, 25302347, 
25302348, 25302349, 25302350, 25302351, 25302352, 25302353, 25302354, 
25302355, 25302356, 25302357, 25302358, 25302359, 25302360, 25302361, 
25302362, 25302363, 25302364, 25302365, 25302366, 25302367, 25302368, 
25302369, 25302370, 25302371, 25302372, 25302373, 25302374, 25302375, 
25302376, 25302377, 25302378, 25302379, 25302380, 25302381, 25302382, 
25302383, 25302384, 25302385, 25302386, 25302387, 25302388, 25302389, 
25302390, 25302391, 25302392, 25302393, 25302394, 25302395, 25302396, 
25302397, 25302398, 25302399, 25302400, 25302401, 25302402, 25302403, 
25302404, 25302405, 25302406, 25302407, 25302408, 25302409, 25302410, 
25302411, 25302412, 25302413, 25302414, 25302415, 25302416, 25302417, 
25302418, 25302419, 25302420, 25302421, 25302422, 25302423, 25302424, 
25302425, 25302426, 25302427, 25302428, 25302429, 25302430, 25302431, 
25302432, 25302433, 25302434, 25302435, 25302436, 25302437, 25302438, 
25302439, 25302440, 25302441, 25302442, 25302443, 25302444, 25302445, 
25302446, 25302447, 25302448, 25302449, 25302450, 25302451, 25302452, 
25302453, 25302454, 25302455, 25302456, 25302457, 25302458, 25302459, 
25302460, 25302461, 25302462, 25302463, 25302464, 25302465, 25302466, 
25302467, 25302468, 25302469, 25302470, 25302471, 25302472, 25302473, 
25302474, 25302475, 25302476, 25302477, 25302478, 25302479, 25302480, 
25302481, 25302482, 25302483, 25302484, 25302485, 25302486, 25302487, 
25302488, 25302489, 25302490, 25302491, 25302492, 25302493, 25302494, 
25302495, 25302496, 25302497, 25302498, 25302499, 25302500, 25302501, 
25302502, 25302503, 25302504, 25302505, 25302506, 25302507, 25302508, 
25302509, 25302510, 25302511, 25302512, 25302513, 25302514, 25302515, 
25302516, 25302517, 25302518, 25302519, 25302520, 25302521, 25302522, 
25302523, 25302524, 25302525, 25302526, 25302527, 25302528, 25302529, 
25302530, 25302531, 25302532, 25302533, 25302534, 25302535, 25302536, 
25302537, 25302538, 25302539, 25302540, 25302541, 25302542, 25302543, 
25302544, 25302545, 25302546, 25302547, 25302548, 25302549, 25302550)
```

Tried doing indexes but either I've created them incorected or it didn't help.

Indexes :

[image]

[EDIT#1]

```
/****** Object:  Index [Features_Data_INDEX]    Script Date: 2021-09-01 10:51:34 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Features_Data_INDEX] ON [dbo].[Features]
(
    [ParentType] ASC,
    [Name] ASC,
    [DataKey] ASC,
    [Lp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [NCI_Features_Parent_ParentType]    Script Date: 2021-09-01 10:59:29 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_Features_Parent_ParentType] ON [dbo].[Features]
(
    [ParentType] ASC,
    [Parent] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [NCI_Features_ParentType_Parent]    Script Date: 2021-09-01 10:59:55 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_Features_ParentType_Parent] ON [dbo].[Features]
(
    [Parent] ASC,
    [ParentType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_Feature]    Script Date: 2021-09-01 11:00:13 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Features] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Feature] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Parent] ASC,
    [ParentType] ASC,
    [Name] ASC,
    [Lp] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

[EDIT#2]
(Estimated) Query plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkyJqphbt

[EDIT#3]
(Actual) Query plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryVNnC2ZY

Comment: For performance advice, please post the query, the query plan and index definitions. The index screenshot you've posted doesn't specify the fields in the index

Comment: I do not have access to the application, I can only see what queries has been sent. When it comes to indexs, no problem - but how should i show it?
Is Script/Create enough, or is there any universal way to show it?

Comment: Yes -script create is the universal way of showing it. You'll need to post the query that is causing issues. Also... if a query suddenly runs slow, first thing to do is rerun statistics

Comment: Thanks, i've added it.

Comment: Please share the query plan (preferably actual rather than estimated) via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: I've added estimated one. Can't do actual atm.

Comment: You need to change this to a joined query, or change the `IN` to `Parent >= 25302311 AND Parent <= 25302550`. If you can't change the query then there is nothing else you can do. Note that index `NCI_Features_ParentType_Parent` is probably extraneous as it's perfectly matched by the clustered index.

Comment: i cant change query, that's the problem :/ I  don't understand why it's so much slower here on SQL Server.  Can actual plan helps in anyway? There must be something I can do

Comment: It's doing a full read of all `ParentType=N'PozycjeDokHan'` rows, then filtering them by `Parent` value, then merging them with the other condition and distincting them. If you could change the query you could speed this up massively by making it do a index seek on each individual value. Ana ctual plan is always more useful because it contains estimated vs actual rows, and it's not always the same plan as the estimated one anyway

Comment: I've done actual one. Maybe it will help.

Comment: So are those `ParentType` filters those same two values every time? You might see a lot of benefit from creating a filtered index `CREATE INDEX FIX_MyIndex ON [dbo].[Features] (Parent) WHERE ParentType IN (N'DokHandlowe',N'PozycjeDokHan')`